# Bluetooth Peripheral ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral, peripherals

I am trying to advertise in NEXUS 9 and getting the error of ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE. It was working perfectly fine when I was adding the service after successfully advertising but if I add the service through Advertise Data builder so that **other devices can filter** while scanning, I get error code 1 i.e ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE

a) Working Code

```
     public void startAdvertisingService() {
    AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
            .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH)
            .setTimeout(0)
            .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)      
            .build();


     AdvertiseData.Builder advertiseData = new AdvertiseData.Builder();
    advertiseData.setIncludeDeviceName(true);

     BluetoothLeAdvertiser myBluetoothLeAdvertiser = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
      myBluetoothLeAdvertiser.stopAdvertising(mAdvertiseCallback);

    myBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(settings, advertiseData.build(),mAdvertiseCallback);

   }
    private AdvertiseCallback mAdvertiseCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
        super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
        BLEBroadcast();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
        String description = "";
        if (errorCode == AdvertiseCallback.ADVERTISE_FAILED_FEATURE_UNSUPPORTED)
            description = "ADVERTISE_FAILED_FEATURE_UNSUPPORTED";
        else if (errorCode == AdvertiseCallback.ADVERTISE_FAILED_TOO_MANY_ADVERTISERS)
            description = "ADVERTISE_FAILED_TOO_MANY_ADVERTISERS";
        else if (errorCode == AdvertiseCallback.ADVERTISE_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED)
            description = "ADVERTISE_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED";
        else if (errorCode == AdvertiseCallback.ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE)
            description = "ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE";
        else if (errorCode == AdvertiseCallback.ADVERTISE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR)
            description = "ADVERTISE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR";
        else description = "unknown";

    }
};
```

and also adding the service:

```
 void BLEBroadcast() {

    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = new     BluetoothGattCharacteristic(characteristicUUID, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);

    BluetoothGattDescriptor desc = new BluetoothGattDescriptor(descriptorUUID, BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_WRITE);
    desc.setValue("".getBytes());

    characteristic.addDescriptor(desc);

    BluetoothGattService service = new BluetoothGattService(serviceUUID,     BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);
    service.addCharacteristic(characteristic);

    mGattServer.addService(service);
 }
```

b) Not working when adding service initially so that can be discovered by central through filter:

calling `BLEBroadcast()` function before calling `startAdvertisingService()` and also adding

```
        AdvertiseData.Builder advertiseData = new AdvertiseData.Builder();
        advertiseData.addServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(serviceUUID));
```

gives advertising failure with error code 1.

Comment: Can you modify your question to show (a) the code that worked "perfectly fine", and (b) the code that does not work?  It isn't clear what changed.

Comment: @davidgyoung I edited my question, hope now you can get me.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I suspect that this is the line of code causing the trouble:

```
advertiseData.setIncludeDeviceName(true);
```

The advertisement will not have enough space for both the device name and a 16 byte service UUID.  So if you include the above then add:

```
advertiseData.addServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(serviceUUID));
```

You will get the error you describe.  Try removing the first line.

Answer (score 5):

Basically your data exceeds 31 bytes, so you need to trim it down.

Change this to false, then it will work:

```
advertiseData.setIncludeDeviceName(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either change your device's name to something shorter.
Example: XYZ_Name_pic - > XYZ

Go to bluetooth -> settings - > rename device name

or you can pass false instead of true

advertiseData.setIncludeDeviceName(false); // pass false not true