# How can we detect android BLE advertisement capable phones

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am now working with BLE technology. Since I have to test with android BLE I have to purchase some android phones that capable of BLE advertisement.

I thought all the phones with BLE version 4.1+ supports BLE advertisement. So I bought a phone but that was a big mistake (it only supports central mode).

**How can I detect which phones are capable of advertisement using the bluetooth specification?**

**What do following terms mean: A2DP, LE, aptX?**

Comment: Related: [Chipsets/Devices supporting Android 5 BLE peripheral mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482611/chipsets-devices-supporting-android-5-ble-peripheral-mode) and (BLE Advertisement in Android)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751253/ble-advertisement-in-android/36751310]. And [here's some data based on a test application](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter-devices.html). It's actually difficult to find that info for a specific phone as it's not interesting for most consumers or for marketing.

Comment: About a year ago I came up with this list based on some heavy googling: Motorola Moto E 4G (2015) / Motorola Moto G (2nd/3rd gen. On 2nd gen. at least `isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()` returns false but a single advertisement works anyway.) / Sony Xperia M4 Aqua / ZTE Blade S6 / Motorola Moto X / Samsung Galaxy S6 / Motorola Google Nexus 6 / HTC One M9 / Samsung Galaxy S6 edge. There may  even be different radio chips e.g. in EU vs. North America models etc. We have successfully used EU version of Motorola Moto G 2nd and 3rd gen.

Comment: Thanks  Markus Kauppinen ,  I know this "isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()" method will return the capability but my question is very specific, if client asks which Samsung or any other branded phones supports my application, how could I answer with phone ble specification?

Comment: "Bluetooth LE peripheral mode" is the necessary technology and if everything else (like the info and links above, info on manufacturer's website) fails, then you just need to contact the manufacturer and ask.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I detect which phones are capable of advertisement using the
>   bluetooth specification?

The device needs to support the [Bluetooth LE Peripheral role](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#roles).

> What do following terms mean: A2DP, LE, aptX?

A2DP is the [Advanced Audio Distribution Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_.28A2DP.29) and is related to audio streaming over Bluetooth. It's not relevant for Bluetooth LE advertising.

[aptX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AptX) is an audio compression algorithm. It's also not relevant for Bluetooth LE advertising.

LE stands for "Low Energy" and refers to "Bluetooth LE" which is a standard for short distance radio communication, part of the Bluetooth 4.0 specification, not compatible with the classic Bluetooth and was developed with the power consumption in mind.