# Why is the Web Bluetooth Device Name Limited to 8 Bytes?

Tags: android, bluetooth

This question is related to the question "[Bluetooth Peripheral ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490649/bluetooth-peripheral-advertise-failed-data-too-large)"

When you set up the AdvertiseData object in Android it is necessary to include a ParcelUuid which should be 16 bytes.  Given that the packet size limit is 31 bytes, I should have 15 bytes leftover to include the device name in the AdvertiseData.

I have tested this and the limit on the device name is 8 bytes; go beyond that and you get the error "ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE".  The simple solution (which was the answer in the issue at the link above) is just to **setIncludeDeviceName(false)** and be done with it; however, I would like to do the following:

**bluetoothAdapter.setName(bluetoothAdapter.getName().substring(0, 8));**

But 8 characters seems to short AND I think I would be programtically changing the bluetooth device name for all applications (this is probably a security flaw which will eventually be closed).

Two questions:

- Where are my missing bytes? ...overhead?
- Is it a bad idea to programtically change the bluetooth device name for all applications?

Thx.

Comment: Is this question related to Web Bluetooth? It seems to be asking about the Android Bluetooth API.

Comment: I removed tag 'web-bluetooth'.  The API does not have 'setName' in 2019. 
 https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/