# "Android.Bluetooth.LE.AdvertiseFailure.DataTooLarge" getting an error while sending data with AddServiceData

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to advertise device id along with service id, below is code, even though if i send only one letter still it is showing same error,can some one please tell me how to add device id in Addservicedata()

private void SendId()

{

string SendcurrentId = Application.Current.Properties["CurrentDeviceId"] as string;

```
        Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
        Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
        byte[] bytesInUni = unicode.GetBytes(SendcurrentId);    
        byte[] bytesInAscii = Encoding.Convert(unicode, ascii, bytesInUni);
        string strUUID = "CDB7950D-73F1-4D4D-8E47-C090502DBD63";
        BluetoothLeAdvertiser advertiser = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.BluetoothLeAdvertiser;
        AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder().SetAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseMode.LowLatency).SetTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseTx.PowerHigh).SetConnectable(false).Build();
        ParcelUuid pUuid = new ParcelUuid(UUID.FromString(strUUID));
        AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
                .SetIncludeDeviceName(true)
                .AddServiceUuid(pUuid)                   
                .AddServiceData(pUuid, bytesInAscii)
                .Build();

        Demodata avertiseCallback = new Demodata();
        advertiser.StartAdvertising(settings, data, avertiseCallback);
    
}
```

Comment: Remove the device name from the advertisement:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490649/bluetooth-peripheral-advertise-failed-data-too-large

Comment: Yes tried that one ...but it's still sayting too large data.

Comment: Add up the total data size, it has to be under 32 bytes

Comment: @SushiHangover yes, its working, added data size under 20 bytes. Thank you!!!